# Beautifulsoup how to select all the 'a' tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am a newbie to BeautifulSoup and Python. Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
<a href="https://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Now my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Getting page souped inside Requests, this part is not necessary 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('a'))
```

This is giving just one link, but I want to get all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `find_all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `.find()`, that will only return the first found, then you have to use `.find_all()` instead to get a list of the a tags.

```
print(soup.find_all('a'))
```

To get href's by for loop:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
  print(link.href)
```